# How can i combine 2 json into 1 using Python

Tags: python

I just start learning about Python and Json. Please go easy on me

I have a something like this

```
o = [{ "name" : "MrA", "Age" : 33 },
     { "name" : "MrB", "Age": 34 }]
p = [{ "place" : "London", "Year" : 2018}, 
     {"place" : "NewYork", "Year":2017}]
```

So what i'm trying to do is to combine them and give them a name like this

```
[
 {"person": [{ "name" : "MrA", "Age" : 33 },
             { "name" : "MrB", "Age": 34 }],
  "cities": [{ "place" : "London", "Year" : 2018},
             {"place" : "NewYork", "Year":2017}]
]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This is not JSON, it's just python lists containing dictionaries.

Comment: Those 2 are lists. You could do: `final = {"persons": o, "cities": p}`.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 object o and p are dictionaries and not json.
However you may try this way to get a json object.

```py
import json

o = [{ "name" : "MrA", "Age" : 33 },
     { "name" : "MrB", "Age": 34 }]
p = [{ "place" : "London", "Year" : 2018}, 
     {"place" : "NewYork", "Year":2017}]

output = {"persons": o, "cities": p}
output = json.dumps(output)
print(output)
```